Rank 2 tensors over $\mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3$?
I am trying to generate a list of all rank 1, 2, 3,... tensors over $\mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3$ in python.
So far I have the rank 1 tensors $a \otimes b \otimes c$, with  $a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}_3$ as a list of pytorch tensors that are basically just vectors in python.
My next step is to sum every combination of two rank 1 tensors to get all the rank at most 2 tensors and subtract off the tensors that are only rank 1.
From what I understand, the rank 2 tensors are all the tensors of the form $a \otimes b \otimes c + a' \otimes b' \otimes c'$, where the two tensors are linearly independent, but I am confused on how this would be represented numerically and then implemented in python.
How do I calculate $a \otimes b \otimes c + a' \otimes b' \otimes c'$? Are the vectors stacked on top of each other to form matrices(in python)? And if the matrix isn't full rank, then it is a rank 1 tensor (I think), so how do I get python to recognize the equivalence?
Just as an example, can someone explain how to calculate a representation of $T=1 \otimes 0 \otimes 2 + 2 \otimes 2 \otimes 1$ for instance?

What is $\mathbb{F}_3$? Do you mean $\mathbb{F}^3 \otimes \mathbb{F}^3 \otimes \mathbb{F}^3$ for some field $\mathbb{F}$?

$\mathbb{F}_3$ (often denoted as $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$) is the finite field with three elements.

That may be, but then the tensor product $\mathbb{F}_3$ with itself (taken over $\mathbb{Z}$) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3$, and the notion of rank for such tensors is trivial. There is some clarification needed.
